# Viewing data returned by ajax in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

In Internet Explorer 9, how is it possible to view data that is returned by an ajax script?

For example, in Firefox using Firebug, The 'All' tab has a 'Response' Sub Tab. that show any data returned by an Ajax Script like below. How is it possible to view this in Internet Explorer?

I have a script that is failing in IE9. It's not a bug or error, but it just wont work. I've cleared the cache etc. etc.

`{"action":"add","close":false,"success":true}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `developer tools`  or press `f12` and in `network tab` you can see xhr request captured and in then click `go to detailed view` button to see the `response`

Comment: Many thanks for helping. You saved me a lot of trouble. I store Browser Agent Strings in MySql, and the column was too small for IE's string. That was the error. For the rest of the Browsers it worked fine.